# How to add a tooltip in HTML when hovering a circle?

Tags: html, tooltip

I am new to html and javascript and i am trying to create a table with circles that when you hover a circle it will present a tooltip with a date inside (the circles represent events)
I used this code in html to create the circles:

```
<td><svg width='50' height='50'><circle cx='2' cy='2' r='2' fill='#ff8B45' /></svg></td>
```

can someone tell me how do I add a tooltip to the circles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `<title>Your text</title>` inside the `<svg>` tag.

```html
<svg width='50' height='50'>
   <circle cx='20' cy='20' r='20' fill='#ff8B45'/>
   <title>11-10-2021</title>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
<td>
    <svg width='50' height='50'>
        <circle cx='2' cy='2' r='2' fill='#ff8B45'>
            <title>11/10/2021</title>
        </circle>
    </svg>
</td>
```

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title)    Text in a <title> element is not rendered as part of the graphic, but browsers **usually** display it as a tooltip. If an element can be described by visible text, it is recommended to reference that text with an aria-labelledby attribute rather than using the <title> element.

Comment: Code only answers are not considered good practice. Please consider [Explaining how this answers the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to the web doc link for tooltip and browser compatibility.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/title